# Implement CodingKey mapping in super class

Tags: swift, struct, swift-protocols

I have a struct that has some properties, a CodingKey enum (in order to conforms to Codable protocol) and some computed-vars that returns an array of keys mapped to string.

What I'm trying to do, is to extract those computed-vars to a protocol (super-class if I have to change the struct to a class) for avoiding to repeat the implementation in every struct/class. And I need **a lot** of them.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to know the CodingKey enum.

Edit:
**DBentity**

```
/// Basic protocol for any object directly related with a database table.
public protocol DBEntity: Codable, Equatable {}
```

The code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// MARK: - Entity Properties

struct AccountsAddresses: DBEntity {

    let statusMobile: String?
    let codeAccount: Int?
    let codeUnitOrg: String?
    let codeSalesOrg: String?
    let codeAddress: Int?
    let codeType: String?
    let byDefault: String?
    let transfered: String?
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// MARK: - Table Columns

extension AccountsAddresses {

    /// Table name.
    static var tableName = "ACCOUNTS_ADDRESSES"

    /// Table columns keys.
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case statusMobile   = "status_mobile"
        case codeAccount    = "code_account"
        case codeUnitOrg    = "code_unit_org"
        case codeSalesOrg   = "code_sales_org"
        case codeAddress    = "code_address"
        case codeType       = "code_type"
        case byDefault      = "by_default"
        case transfered
    }

/* This is what I'm trying to extract to a protocol(extension) or super-class. */

    /// All table columns keys.
    static var columns: [String] = CodingKeys.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
    static var columnsJoined: String = columns.joined(separator: String.commaSpace)
    static var columnsTableName: [String] = columns.map { tableName + String.dot + $0 }
    static var columnsJoinedTableName: String = columnsTableName.joined(separator: String.commaSpace)
}
```

**EDIT**

Using the given code from Sweeper's answer, I'm trying to implement the protocol in a new struct, but the compiler asks to set a type to the typealias CodingKeyType (since the defined protocol has the associatedtype).

```
public protocol Table {
    associatedtype ColumnKeysType: (CodingKey & CaseIterable & RawRepresentable)
    static var tablename: String { get }
}
```

Here the struct to test:

```
struct AccountsTest: Table {

    typealias CodingKeyType = <#type#>
}
```

I've tried to make another struct in order to have a type to assign to the typealias, but there's something that I'm missing/doing wrong (I had to implement this vars, constructors & typealias).

```
struct Keys: (CodingKey & CaseIterable & RawRepresentable) {

    var stringValue: String
    var rawValue: String
    var intValue: Int?

    init?(stringValue: String) {}
    init?(rawValue: String) {}
    init?(intValue: Int) {}

    typealias AllCases = Keys.RawValue
    typealias RawValue = String
}
```

The compiler continues showing errors and I can't find the way to accomplish this.

```
'CaseIterable' requires the types 'Keys' and 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') be equivalent
```

Any tip to get this done?

Thank you

Comment: So what is DBEntity?

Comment: @matt (post edited) DBEntity is protocol for any object directly related with a database table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the properties you are trying to extract are not computed properties.

The properties you want to extract seems to only depend on `tableName` and `CodingKeys`, so we can write a protocol like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    associatedtype CodingKeyType : (CodingKey & CaseIterable & RawRepresentable)
    static var tableName: String { get }
}
```

and then an extension like this (I have converted the properties to computed properties):

```
extension SomeProtocol where CodingKeyType.RawValue == String {
    static var columns: [String] { return CodingKeyType.allCases.map { $0.rawValue } }
    static var columnsJoined: String { return columns.joined(separator: " ") }
    static var columnsTableName: [String] { return columns.map { tableName + "." + $0 } }
    static var columnsJoinedTableName: String { return columnsTableName.joined(separator: " ") }
}
```

Comment: You're completely right, I was wrong about the computed properties (what a mistake). Thankyou so much for the answer! This is exactly what I was looking for! You rock!

Comment: I've edit the original post to add new code that is showing me errors. I cannot find a type to set to the typealias CodingKeyType...

Comment: @JavierFernandezMartínez you should put the `CodingKeys` Enum as the typealias. There is no need to create a new type.

Comment: I already tried that: typealias ColumnKeysType = CodingKeys but the compiler continued showing errors. My mistake now was that I removed accidentally the protocols CodingKey, CaseIterable from the CodingKeys enum. Now is working as expected. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do the conversion by yourself. You can use `decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase` and your json will get mapped to your camel case properties.

For More information:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase

Comment: thankyou for the answer! I'd tried working with the keyDecodingStrategy but (unfortunately) some keys are not conforming an exactly snakecase naming.